# Invalid Json primitive error - api call result

Tags: json, vb.net

I am getting following data with the api call -

```
[{
    "generated_at": 1371490821,
    "status": "success",
    "station_id": 1,
    "station_name": "Hits Radio FM",
    "developer_id": 24,
    "count": 5,
    "refresh_url": "https://api.xxx.com/1/GET/nowplaying.json?api_key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&station_id=1&count=5",
    "next_results_url": "https://api.xxx.com/1/GET/nowplaying.json?api_key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&station_id=1since_id=85",
    "since_id": 85,
    "tracks": {
        "0": [{
            "id": 80,
            "artist": "Robbie Williams",
            "artist_id": 314,
            "title": "Candy"
            "likes": 215,
            "youtube_id": "gtOV7bp-gys",
            "coverart_url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdukt9rJoI1rj7xj3o1_500.jpg",
            "spotify_url": "https://play.spotify.com/track/6cskzfZWgrgd8hv74fHd9o",
            "itunes_url": "https://itunes.apple.com/nl/album/candy-single/id558817147",
            "playedtime": 1371490752,
            "likedByUser": 0
        }],
        "1": [{ /* the same layout as above */ }],
        "2": [{ /* the same layout as above */ }],
        "3": [{ /* the same layout as above */ }],
        "4": [{ /* the same layout as above */ }]
    }
}]
```

When i am trying to deserialize this data using JavaScriptSerializer, i am getting the error message "Invalid JSON primitive".

Can anybody help me out resolve this issue.

I am having following classes used to holding data.

```
Public Class ResponseTrackInfo
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim artist As String
    Dim artist_id As Integer
    Dim title As String
    Dim likes As Integer
    Dim youtube_id As String
    Dim coverart_url As String
    Dim spotify_url As String
    Dim itunes_url As String
    Dim playedtime As Integer
    Dim likedByUser As Integer
End Class
```

and

```
Public Class ResponseNowPlayingInfo
    Dim generated_at As Integer
    Dim status As String
    Dim station_id As Integer
    Dim station_name As String
    Dim developer_id As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim refresh_url As String
    Dim next_results_url As String
    Dim since_id As Integer
    Dim tracks As List(Of ResponseTrackInfo)

    Public Sub New()
        tracks = New List(Of ResponseTrackInfo)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the code

```
Private Sub CallApiToGetLiveEvents()
        Dim apiResponse As WebResponse
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim apiUrl As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("My_URL")

        Dim apiKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("My_ApiKey")
        Dim stationId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("My_StationId")
        apiUrl = String.Format(apiUrl, apiKey, stationId)


        Dim uri As New Uri(apiUrl)
        request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
        apiResponse = request.GetResponse()

        If Not (apiResponse Is Nothing) Then
            Dim data1(apiResponse.ContentLength) As Byte

            apiResponse.GetResponseStream().Read(data1, 0, data1.Length)

            Dim d = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data1)

            Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer
            Dim decoded = ser.Deserialize(Of List(Of ResponseNowPlayingInfo))(d)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a comma after

```
"title": "Candy"
```

in your JSON object, which gives the parser really a hard time to parse this thing as JSON. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, try use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON

You are missing a commna after `"title": "Candy"`

Answer (score -3):

Try to pass the JSON string into textbox and then deserialize it from textbox.text

Comment: If the JSON is invalid, it's irrelevant how it is transported to the script parsing it